# How to validate a string field in sequelize.js?

Tags: node.js, validation, sequelize.js

How can I validate a database field to accept just a string?

In my database, I have two fields:

1. `description`: String
2. `completed`: Boolean

I want the description field accept just a string value. What I mean is:

- 'description':'text' =>  database accept this request
- 'descrition': true or false  => database refuse this request
- 'descrition': 123  => database refuse this request

Currently, the `description` field can accept a boolean value , so there is an issue in my configuration.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('todo', {
        description: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false,
            validate: {
                len: [1, 250],
                isBoolean:false,
                isAlpha:true
            }
        },
        completed: {
            type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: false,
            validate:{
                isBoolean:true
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regexp validation, to check that the value is string and it's value not `true` or `false`:

```
return sequelize.define('todo', {
    description: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull:false,
        validate: {
            is: ^((?!true|false|TRUE|FALSE).){1,255}$
        }
    },
    ...
```

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#validations

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP wants.  They say *The description field can accept a boolean variable so there is an issue in my configuration* which makes me think they don't want to be able to enter true but they can.  Could be wrong though but just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , i want  just the description field accept just a string value not boolean so i tried just the first part of your answer : is: [a-z|A-Z]{1,250}  and also tryed this is: /^[a-z]+$/i, but doesn't work , i don't want description accept a boolean value

Comment: @NathanOliver, yes, you're right, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @Zola please check the new answer.

Comment: Why do we still need to manually enforce validation, isn't the type declaration enough to make sequelize/underlying database to make sure the input is actually a string?

Comment: @Yos OP wants to validate that value is a string, and it's in a special format. How to validate that with type declaration?